# Doctrine update use join error

Tags: sql, join, doctrine-orm

I need run this sql.

```
$this->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')
    ->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->update()
    ->join('o.dis', 'd')
    ->set('o.channel.type', 'CASE WHEN d.hasVod = 1 THEN :vod ELSE :other END')
    ->setParameter('vod', 'vod')
    ->setParameter('other', 'other)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute()
;
```

Or

```
$this->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')
    ->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->update()
    ->join('o.dis', 'd')
    ->set('o.channel.type', 'vod')
    ->where('d.hasVod = 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute()
;
```

But Error: 'd' is not defined.
I try run sql in Doctrine also has this error.

So if you has good idea, Please tell me, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define table d in join instruction. 
The beginning of query would be:

```
$this->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')
    ->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->join('YourBundle:YourEntity', 'd','WITH', 'd.id = o.dis' )
/* ...... */
```

Comment: The way failed, error still is 'd' is not defined.
result Sql not has join entity.